# How to do an ElasticSearch date historgram aggregation for 'next 7 days'

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I would like to use an ElasticSearch aggregation over a date field, where each 'bucket' is values on that date.

I started with this:

```
"aggs" : {
    "auctions" : {
        "date_histogram" : {
            "field" : "auctionOn",
            "interval" : "day"
        }
    }
}
```

But it returns too many buckets. I only want buckets for the next 7 days.

I also have a bunch of other aggregations, so the filter needs to apply to only *this* aggregation.

Any ideas?

I'm also using the NEST client for .NET, so bonus if you can help me figure out how to do in with the NEST client (but i should be able to figure it out, once i have the ES query to use)

Thanks

Comment: Use histogram aggregation in filter aggregation.

Comment: @Nishant Saini can you chuck an answer up with some example code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date_histogram` aggregation in `filter` aggregation to apply filter for specific aggregation.

So the aggregation would look like:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "filter_hist": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "auctionOn": {
            "gte": "2018-12-01",
            "lte": "2018-12-21"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hist": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "auctionOn",
            "interval": "1d"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can change the `range` filter according to your needs.

Comment: Nishant or @RussCam any ideas how to port this to the NEST client? I can't see how to apply a filter to an aggregation (only to the main query)

Comment: I can't help you with NEST. @RussCam can.

Comment: This might be of help: [Filter Aggregation: NEST](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/filter-aggregation-usage.html#_object_initializer_syntax_example_123)

Comment: ah.. cool, not sure how i didn't find that (sometimes the docs are hard to navigate :) ) i should be able to figure it out.. thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to apply a `range` query on the date field, which will be applied before aggregations are calculated.

Since it sounds like you're executing multiple aggregations in one request however, and this date range should only be applied to one aggregation, you can execute an [`msearch` or multi search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) to retrieve multiple results in one request. This is what Kibana uses for example, to retrieve results for multiple visualizations in a dashboard.

Something like

```cs
public class MyDocument
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime AuctionOn { get; set; }
}

var client = new ElasticClient();

var multiSearchResponse = client.MultiSearch(ms => ms
    .Search<MyDocument>("main_aggs", s => s
        .Aggregations(a => a
            .Terms("titles", t => t
                .Field(f => f.Title)
            )
            .Terms("content", t => t
                .Field(f => f.Content)
            )
        )
    )
    .Search<MyDocument>("date_agg", s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .DateRange(dr => dr
                .Field(f => f.AuctionOn)
                .GreaterThanOrEquals(DateMath.Now)
                .LessThan(DateMath.Now.Add("7d"))
            )
        )
        .Aggregations(a => a
            .DateHistogram("auctions", dh => dh
                .Field(f => f.AuctionOn)
                .Interval(DateInterval.Day)
            )
        )
    )
);

var mainAggsResponse = multiSearchResponse.GetResponse<MyDocument>("main_aggs");

var dateAggResponse = multiSearchResponse.GetResponse<MyDocument>("date_agg");
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Russ. Does that mean Nishants answer is incorrect, since the filter would apply to other aggregations?

Comment: @RPM1984 No, the Filter aggregation only applies to aggregations nested underneath it. It's another solution to the problem

Comment: interesting. What's the differences in the two solutions? Below one seems to do it in one round trip? (Which I know isn't always necessarily a good thing)

Comment: They both do it in one roundtrip. Nishant's solution is useful where you want to apply the filter to the aggregation only e.g. you may be returning documents also but want to show facets with a filter applied. This solution allows you to returning multiple searches in one request

Comment: got it. i only need to apply the filter to the aggregations, so i think Nishant's might be better. i misspoke RE round trips. i meant this does two _searches_, Nishan't only does one. the question is: what's more performant: 2 searches (1 for the documents, another for the aggregation), or 1 search which includes both the documents and aggregations with filters applied. i would have thought the latter? it _sounds_ like since i only need the filter for the aggregation, Nishant's might be better?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure which will be faster. Might want to benchmark both with your data

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what i'll do. Will do that and report back. +1 for both answers for now :)